# Hyperlinks and References not working with the standalone package

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing, standalone

I'm trying to combine two separate documents into a single document and want them to share a combined bibliography. I'm using the `standalone` package for the same.

`main.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true,mode=build]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone{first}
\newpage
\includestandalone{second}
\newpage
\newgeometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{publications}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

`first.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[]{first}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah...
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{Tex StackExchange}
blah blah blah~\cite{Jain2021}
```

`first.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[]{first}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah...
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{Tex StackExchange}
blah blah blah~\cite{Jain2021}
\end{document}
```

`second.tex` is almost the same as `first.tex`

There are two issues with this, references to bibliography show up as [?] and the resulting document contains no hyperlinks, i.e., only the text is visible but no hyperlink is there.
Is there any way to fix both these issues?

Comment: \includestandalone, same as \includegraphics, converts the PDF into an image (no hyperlinks).  I would use \include and \includeonly, although that requires starting on a new page each time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't mind starting a new page each time, could you let me know how I could use \include with subdocuments that each have their own preamble?

Comment: You can also combine files using the xr package which can handle \rel and \label, but I'm not sure about hyperlinks.  Those are written directly to the PDF, not the aux file.

Comment: The `xr` package doesn't solve the issue when referencing the bibliography.